# How could Acrobat Reader's installer detect that I am Pole / in Poland

Tags: installation, language, adobe-reader, installer

I am a Pole, living in Poland, but I am using virtually everything in English, starting with version of Windows 10, going through all my apps and ending up with Chrome settings and default lanugage of all pages that I am browsing.

Yet, during my recent installation of Acrobat Reader DC the installer program was in Polish:

[image]

Do we have any chance investigating how was that possible?

After above depicted installer has finished its job, the actual language of installed Acrobat Reader was in fact (as expected) English. As every other piece of software on my PC.

But, I still wonder, based on what that installer detected Polish language and displayed itself in Polish, if virtually anything in my PC / Windows is in English and I haven't seen my native language here for a couple of past months.

I have obtained the installer file that I used from an official website. And prior to downloading, page correctly detected that I need an English version of that file:

[image]

So, what am I missing here?

Is it possible that it detected language based on my IP address (initially I have downloaded just the 1,2 MB bootstrap file that downloaded remaining 150+ MB of an actual installer through my Internet connection)?

Comment: Have you tried to install via a VPN using a server not in Poland? This will allow to know if  the installer checks your IP address during the installation.

Comment: They can easily access your IP, yes. Everyone can track where an IP is from. Adobe probably does it.

Comment: Nuff said trejder.  Sorry! :) Comment revoked.  I did not mean to offend.  I myself am appalled that PDF hasn't changed but the viewer went from 5MB to 150+MB.. ***Sumatra PDF*** is one of many that work well, is standalone, and has a footprint of 5MB.

Comment: @SeñorCMasMas Nothing personal taken! :) I took this purely as a joke. I do agree with you that these "full featured PDF viewers" are very, very huge bastards these days! :)